# PrimeFaces dataTable: how to catch rows-per-page event?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I cretated a PrimeFaces dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable id="locationTable" value="#{bean.object}" var="item"
  paginator="true"
  rows="10" 
  paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink}{LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
  rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,30,50,100">
  ...
</p:dataTable>
```

I'd like to save the dropdown box value for rows-per-page. When the user changes the value, how would I catch the event? So I can read and save one of the "5,10,15,20,30,50,100" values in order for this to apear automatically next time the user comes back to this page. Currently, it is not saved, so every time the page is (re)loaded, it goes back to default value of "10".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that like this:

**The View**

```
<h:form id="mainForm">

    <p:dataTable id="locationTable" value="#{datatableBean.list}" var="item"
                 paginator="true" widgetVar="dtVar"
                 rows="#{datatableBean.rows}" 
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="1,2,3,4,5,6">
        <p:column>
            #{item.name}
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:remoteCommand name="persistRows" action="#{datatableBean.saveRows}" process="@this" 
                     update="rows" global="false" />

    <h:outputText id="rows" value="#{datatableBean.rows}" />

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            dtVar.paginator.rppSelect.change(function() {
                persistRows([{name: 'rows', value: this.value}]);
            });
        });
    </script>
</h:form>
```

**The Bean**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DatatableBean implements Serializable {

    private int rows;

    private List<SimpleBean> list;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        //default rows value
        rows = 2;

        list = new ArrayList<SimpleBean>();
        //ID and Name
        list.add(new SimpleBean(11, "A"));
        list.add(new SimpleBean(22, "B"));
        list.add(new SimpleBean(33, "C"));
    }

    public void saveRows(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String rowsStr = (String) map.get("rows");
        rows = Integer.parseInt(rowsStr);
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(int rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public List<SimpleBean> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<SimpleBean> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

The strategy here is to extend the onchange event associated with the html **select** tags rendered by the paginator. To facilitate that task, I've set the wigetVar in the datatable (**dtVar**) knowing that it's clientside api gives us both selects through **dtVar.paginator.rppSelect**.

Now, to be able to send the value on those selects to the managed bean, we can use a remoteCommand. Using the remoteCommand component we can send javascript parameters to a managedbean. I've named the remoteCommand as **persistRows** and by calling it I've specified the extra parameters using the pattern required by the component: **[{name: 'rows', value: this.value}]** ([{name: 'nameOfTheVariable', value: 'valueOfTheVariable'}]).

Now you can do whatever you want to do with that rows attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite get it, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I mean, I tried it and it doesn't work, it "forgets" the rows-per-page as soon as I refresh the page.

Comment: I've updated the question to explain the strategy. I've tested that sample code on Primefaces 4 and it worked as expected. If the explanation isn't enough, send us more of you code to enable us to simulate it more precisely.

Comment: OK, thanks. So, in the code above, the `rows` isn't saved anywhere, I need to save it in order to revert to it on another page load?

Comment: It's saved on @SessionScoped. That's why it should be working on page reload.

Comment: OK. My bean is ViewScoped. I saved it as session var, now it works, thank you so much for your help. The problem now is how to implement this same thing in several pages without having too much code repetition?

Comment: I am not well versed in jquery and javascript: can I move the javascript code to scripts.js? What needs to be changed in `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ dtVar.paginator.rppSelect.change(function(){ persistRows([{name: 'rows', value: this.value}]); }); });` to be able to move it?

Comment: I believe you should persist it as some sort of user preference and then create a SessionScoped bean to retrieve the persisted user preferences from datatable. I've done something similar to store the user preferred theme. To avoid adding columns to every possible user preference, you could store a json string and then do something creative to consume it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46353/discussion-between-daniel-camargo-and-danijel)

Comment: What's the purpose of `<h:outputText id="rows" value="#{datatableBean.rows}" />` here?

Comment: Just to prove that the value is actually being updated. It's not important to the solution.

Comment: OK, figured it out, and removed. Thanks.

Comment: be careful if you need to update the dataTable, if you do this, you need to reload the javascript, so, if you need to update the dataTable, put the dataTable and the script inside a panelGroup and update him instead of dataTable;

Answer (score 3):

I posted this solution to another question, and I'm sharing it because I hope someone might find it simpler to implement than Daniel's (which still taught me a lot about JQuery!)

My solution is using Primefaces 5.2.x.

I found a pretty easy way to implement this, one of the problems I had was that when the onPaginate() method was called, it didn't have the newest selected value.

So here's what I did to make sure you always had the latest value and could save/load it to the database or a cookie or something (we save to a cookie).

```
<p:dataTable
        .....
        paginator="true"
        paginatorPosition="bottom"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        currentPageReportTemplate="Total records: {totalRecords}, showing page {currentPage} of {totalPages}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100"
        rows="#{controller.rowsPerPage}"
        .....
    >
        .....
        <p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="rowsPerPageUpdate()" />
        .....
</p:dataTable>
<p:remoteCommand name="rowsPerPageUpdate" actionListener="#{controller.onPaginate}" />
```

and then our controller looks like this:

```
@Dependent
@Named
public class TableController implements Serializable {
    private String rowsPerPage = "25"; //default value
    .....
    public void onPaginate() {
        //save to the cookie
    }
    .....
}
```

Basically the magic happens in the remoteCommand, which will fire after the ajax event to insure that controller.rowsPerPage has been properly updated.

Comment: If people only started using the lazy model. So much simpler than all these workarounds

Answer (score 1):

I've searched for a solution too and after reading this thread I've found out that there's a new Primefaces feature which allows you to save the state of the datatable.

So for Primefaces v6.0.10+ you can simply add `multiViewState="true"`.

Note that this will also save filter, sorting, current page and selection beside rows per page.

Here's the link to the official demo of this feature: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/multiViewState.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way that what is written above (tested with Primefaces 7.X) is to simply use the accessors method. This solution has the advantage to have the actual number of row being set. Otherwise, in my case I would obtain the previous number of row, before it is changed ...

```
<p:dataTable
        .....
        paginator="true"
        paginatorPosition="bottom"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        currentPageReportTemplate="Total records: {totalRecords}, showing page {currentPage} of {totalPages}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100"
        rows="#{controller.rowsPerPage}"
        .....
    >
        .....
        .....
</p:dataTable>
```

And the bean should simply look like :

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class Controller implements Serializable {
    private int rowsPerPage = 25; //default value

    public int getRowsPerPage() {
      return rowsPerPage;
    }

    /** Will be called each time the number or selected rows change */
    public void setRowsPerPage(int rows){
      this.rowsPerPage = rows; 
      // Do some other stuff, like using a cache to store the value
    }
}
```

I personally use a cache storing the number of rows per user and entity types.

Comment: Could you show how exactly you use cache to store the value?

Comment: By the time I written this I've changed the way of doing it. Now I store this in the session's cookies

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution like this

```
<p:dataTable

.....

<p:ajax event="page" listener="#{yourBean.onPaginate}" />

...
 </p:dataTable>
```

This is your bean

```
public void onPaginate(PageEvent event)
    {
        String pageSizeParam = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("parameter name");

....
```

With "parameter name", you can check on F12, Network tab -> payload