# PrimeFaces paginator selection

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a PrimeFaces (5) DataTable and like to store the page size selection in the view, so that the user sees the same number of rows when he returns to the view.

But all I see from documentation is that there is a `page` event which can be captured, but which won't give me the currently selected page size. The closest I got was getting the event's source (the DataTable) and get the rows attribute, but it only contains the number of rows *before* applying the new value.

Here on SO, I found [a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381846/primefaces-datatable-how-to-catch-rows-per-page-event), but it seems to me not the best way to implement it having to use some inline JQuery stuff.

It seems to me a not-so-exotic feature to persist the page size selection within the session, so there must be a good solution for it, I assume?

Comment: I **always** use a lazyDataModel, since that gives me full control in an easy way.  But I think you can get the component in you event,  cast that to a datatable and get the page size from that

Comment: @Kukeltje: As I said above, I did that, but it won't help, since it's before the change. Could you elaborate on your usage of the lazyDataModel and how it would help here?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post ( or did you edit ;-)) In a lazy datamodel load method you have access to the page size that you can put somewhere in a viewscope or any scope of your choice (longer than request). But keep in mind that since the load method is called in the render phase, you only have access to the value you export in EL that is AFTER the datatable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noticed, the `page` event is being fired *before* the selected number of rows has been applied to the table. At the moment, there is no event being fired *after* changing the number of rows.

**However, there is a possible workaround:**

- bind your datatable to the backing bean
- Use AJAX `page`-event without any listener. Instead, call a `<p:remoteCommand>` after ajax request is complete.
- Add your actionListener method to the `<p:remoteCommand>`.
- Within this method, check the datatable's number of rows. It's the new value.
- Keep in mind, `page` event is not only fired when changing the number of rows, but also on page change.

**Example:**

XHTML/JSF

```
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand  name="pageChanged" actionListener="#{tableBean.onPageChanged}"/>
    <p:dataTable binding="#{tableBean.table}" paginator="true"  rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20" rows="5">
        <p:ajax event="page" process="@none"  oncomplete="pageChanged()" />
           <!-- columns here -->
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

TableBean.java

```
private DataTable table;

public void onPageChanged(){
   int numRows = table.getRows();
   // ...
}

//getter/setter for table
```

Comment: Ok, I still wonder why it's not designed to be capturable directly, but this workaround seems easy and understandable enough, I'll try it, thanx.

Comment: Most likely since not many people need access to it at the time/spot/.. you do.  In my 5 years with PF, I've almost never seen this requirement by people not using a lazyDataModel